# Étendue géographique de l'expression « être de piquet » ?

Tags: expressions, régionalismes, suisse, travail

Ne trouvant pas cette expression sur Internet, je me pose la question de savoir si ce n'est pas une expression régionale typiquement suisse.

La définition que j'en donnerais en français serait :

> Être atteignable en dehors des heures de travail dans le cas d'une urgence dans le but de répondre au téléphone ou de se rendre sur son lieu de travail.
>
> Exemple :
>   — Je pensais qu'on pourrait se faire une balade dans la forêt, ce week-end.
>   — Impossible, je suis de piquet, il faut que je puisse me rendre au travail en dix minutes.
>
> On peut être de piquet la nuit, le week-end, à Noël, etc.

Est-ce une expression francophone ou régionale ? (Et comment le dire en français si c'est une expression régionale ?)

(Et par hasard, connaîtriez-vous un équivalent anglais de cette expression ?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Il semblerait qu'*être de piquet* soit une expression suisse.

Pour un emploi professionnel (France) on utilisera ***être d'astreinte***, ce qui signifie que l'on doit pouvoir se rendre sur son lieu de travail dans les délais convenus.

(Lien pratique vers [les suggestions de linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%EAtre+d%27astreinte) pour ce qui concerne l'anglais.)

Answer (score 10):

Comme indiqué par cl-r dans sa [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6536/1129), *être de piquet* serait effectivement un régionalisme suisse, comme semblent le confirmer les rares [références](http://goupil79.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/le-service-de-piquet-kezako/) modernes sur le net.

*Être de garde* est une variante possible, même si selon les métiers (médecine en particulier) cela implique d'être sur son lieu de travail.

Pour ce qui est de la traduction en anglais, on pourra utiliser *[to be on call](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on+call)* (avant-dernière section).

Answer (score 8):

Il semblerait plutôt que ce soit une expression d'origine militaire, je vous encourage à lire par exemple l'*Ordonnance du Roy sur le maniement des armes de l'infanterie française et étrangère* du 7 mai 1750 ou l'*Instruction pratique* du 5 septembre 1902: *Service en campagne* son article 85 définit le piquet.

Le piquet est donc « La partie disponible de la fraction de jour prend le nom de piquet. Elle est destinée à fournir les détachements et les gardes qui peuvent être commandés extraordinairement.
Le piquet est sous les ordres de l'officier supérieur de jour.
Il est interdit aux hommes de piquet de sortir de leur cantonnement ou bivouac, si ce n'est pour le service. »

Comment: Excellente information ! Je ne la choisie pas comme réponse car elle indique l'origine et non la portée géographique actuelle, mais +1 quand-même !

Answer (score 6):

À mon avis c'était une expression tout ce qu'il a de plus française, mais autour de 68 elle s'est de plus en plus spécialisée vers le « piquet de grève ».

L'expression *être de piquet* signifie dans ce contexte occuper son lieu de travail pour empêcher les autres travailleurs de travailler normalement. L'exact contraire d'une astreinte.

Comment: Tiens j'aurais pas fait l'accord à *français(e)*.

Comment: J'écris comme je parle. A l'intuition.