# Why "en" instead of "y" in “la définition que j'en donnerais”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

In the body of this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6532/etendue-geographique-de-lexpression-etre-de-piquet), one can read the following sentence:

> La définition que j'en donnerais en français serait [...].

I would like to know why the asker used **en**, instead of **y**, since **donner** exists only in combinations with **à**, which is the "trigger" (if you will) of **y**, not **en**.

So why didn't the asker write, *La définition que j'**y** donnerais en français serait [...]* instead?

Isn't *La définition que je donnerais **à** ce mot en français serait [...]* the correct interpretation of this sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*En* ici remplace un complément de *définition*, pas un complément de *donner*.  Et ce complément commence bien par *de*.

> La définition **de XYZ** que je donnerais en français [...]

Comment: Et où est ce complément qui commence par _de_ dans le texte de la question? Je ne peux pas l'y voir.

Comment: @indoxica: On peut tout à fait dire « *la définition que je donnerais **de XYZ** en français [...]* », ce qui explique la structure de la phrase. Ça peut paraitre étrange mais il arrive qu'un complément dans une subordonnée complémente l'antécédent.

Comment: I couldn't have found a better explanation than that...

Answer (score 3):

Pour une astuce mnémotechnique par rapport à *donner* : *y* indique une localisation, un lieu, un endroit, un espace :

> "La salle A2? j'y donnerai un cours demain !"

Sinon on emploie *en*.

Comment: Pour le coup, "La définition que j'y donnerais" est parfaitement correct si on s'adresse à de vieilles personnes dans la campagne du Berry.

Comment: @Fabinout Tout est une question de contexte : le lieu futur (*j'y donnerai*) est précisé ou sous-entendu sans ambigüité, il n'y a pas de malentendu possible.